# Reports are not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, telerik, reporting

I created a Web Application that will display the reports that I made using Telerik Reporting. It was all fine not until when I deploy it. It's now working on different browsers except IE. when I open the web app using chrome, I can clearly see my report but when I open it using IE, all I can see is a blank report.
I need help on how I can fix this, do you think the problem is in my solution or some settings in the IE? if so, please help me fix it.

Comment: do you see any script errors or anything in the F12 developer tools?

Comment: there's no error. actually when you open it in IE it's a blank report but when you export it in PDF file and save it. when you open the PDF, the report is actually there.

Comment: Normally this problem has to do with the html markup. Try fixing the dimensions of the div containing the report.

Comment: I really can't find the error. the local solution is really fine but after I deploy it in the server so that the other PC can also access the report, that's when we encounter this problem. it's all after it is deployed. do you think there's properties or settings that changed during the deployment process?

Comment: Kendo reports, ASPNET AJAX or MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can write these lines of code inside your Page_Load or put the meta in your head section of your HTML:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpBrowserCapabilities bc;
    bc = Request.Browser;

    if (bc.Browser == "InternetExplorer")
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
    }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

Hope it helps.